# How to access activity in viewGroup

Tags: java, android

Now i am going on with the transparency of screen.

What i need is when drag a slider down with `ACTION_MOVE` method along with the (x,y)coordinates the opacity should also get differ.

Actually i had my screen seperately which is declared as extends activity class and my dragger is of extends viewgroup.

For that i had declared the variable static of the layout and tried to access it in extends viewgroup class.

It causes me null point error

Here what i had tried:

```
public class NextViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        // Log.i ( "Inside Action Move", "" );

    if ( event.getY() >= 560 && CameraFlag == 0 ) {
       MyActivity.sample();
    }
}
```

Activity class:

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
        public boolean status = false;
        Button first, second;
        public  static LinearLayout layout;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
            layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.transparency);
        }

public static void sample()
 {
 try
 { layout.getBackground().setAlpha(30); 
}
 catch (Exception e) 
{ 
e.printStackTrace(); }
}
    }
```

If anyone have idea about this please help me friends.

Comment: It is better to define an interface and use a callback in your `nextActivity`. Then your `MyActivity` can implement that interface and be notified when the slider is moved. That way, your `LinearLayout` doesn't have to be declared static (which isn't nice in the first place). btw, it is not best practice to name your class `nextActivity` if it extends `ViewGroup`. It would be better no name it `NextViewGroup`

Comment: can u please share me any sample regarding this procedure.

Comment: i tried it as you told but it remains the same null point error.

Comment: MyActivity:public static void sample()
{
try {
layout.getBackground().setAlpha(30);

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();

}}
                                                                      NextViewGroup :  if ( event.getY() >= 560 && CameraFlag == 0 ) {
       ProfileActivity.sample();
    }

Comment: You are now using a static function, which is not the same as an interface. Take a look at this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html to understand java interfaces. You would define an interface in nextViewGroup and implement it in your activity. Then you can give nextViewGroup a so called listener (an instance of the interface, in this case your activity) and let nextViewGroup call function from that interface (which you implemented in your activity)